# How can you know if an issue with or lack of feature on a certain software is a business case or technical one?

Tags: crystal-reports

After some googling-fu on making subscript text in crystal report, I found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vscrystalreports/thread/bbd5171e-12ed-4b88-8aae-5e716c917e41), [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/ShowMessages.aspx?ThreadID=30895) and numerous others.

My question is, how can you know if a problem (or lack of feature) on a certain software is a business case or technical one?

A part of me tells that this is a business case (Business Object(SAP?)), they want to squeeze money from every features. Though a part of me tells me that this is a technical one, Crystal Version is on its 11th version already, yet they still don't know how to add subscript capability for text.

Like the MERGE statement of MSSQL 2005 it was there in its beta (I just read somewhere), but was removed when released, the feature was deferred to 2008.  this has a business case ring to me more than a technical case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've done extensive research on the subject and have found no solution to the problem it is likely to be a business case. The simplest way to have this confirmed though is by contacting the vendor, they should be able to clarify this.

It is usually a technical case when the feature is not documented (even at this point the bell rings why not document a feature?) but it seems that this is not the case here.